# И еще о слове "чур"

Tags: этимология, лексика

А вообще, интересно, что это за слово "чур"? Насколько я знаю, "чур меня" — это что-то вроде заклинания от злых духов. "Чураться" — сторониться. Но почему тогда это слово употребляется и в том значении, как приведено в предыдущем вопросе — в значении "пусть" или как-то так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ожегов называет еще одно значение слова "чур" : "возглас (обычно в детских играх), которым запрещают касаться чего-нибудь, переходить за какой-нибудь предел (первоначально в заклинаниях, где слово "чур" означает границу, межу".

Answer (score 2):

Я не знаю, о каком "предыдущем" вопросе идет речь, но не вижу ничего взаимоисключающего в этих двух (или даже более) значениях.

Есть версия, что "чур" - происходит от "щур" - далекий предок. Заклинание духом предков вполне самодостаточное объяснение для всех перечисленных случаев. "Чур меня" = "охраните сеня, предки". "Чураться" - "охрантяься" (хотя может, это и случайное созвучие, у меня нет полной уверенности в родстве чура и чуратся), "Чур я (первый)" - именем предков - я такой-то!
Хотя повторюсь, ролдство "чур и "щур" ещё предстоит доказать. Но независмо от этого родства "чур" в приводимых примерах имеет именно такое значение, слова-оберега.

Comment: А "щур" -- это точно "далёкий предок"?

Интересно было узнать. А то вот в украинском языке иногда употребляется слово **"прАщуры"**, как раз в таком смысле -- "далёкие предки", с несколько торжественным оттенком. *Прадеды*, к примеру -- это понятно. Слово *дед* с приставкой *пра-*.

:-) А *щур* в современном украинском языке -- это *крыса*. Так что *"пращуры"* вовсе не понять что получается. Вот Вы мне загадку разгадали. Большое спасибо. +1.

Comment: Слово пращур есть и в русском языке. Только путаницы с "крысой" не получается.

Comment: Щур: http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/269406/%D0%A9%D1%83%D1%80  При этом, изначально щур - это дше (иди прадед), кажетсмя, по материнской линии. Но это значение быстро потерялось, став переносным (как деды/прадеды = предки вообще), о чем и говорит Ефремова.

Answer (score 2):

Чур, еще это обрядовая кукла, вырезанная из дерева, "божок". Воплощенный в дереве хранитель рода. Чурбан, чурка - видимо однокоренные, указывают на древесное происхождение :)

Comment: Да! Не возражаете, я ваш коммент до ответа повысил? 
Чур - действительно божок, идол, это вещь довольно известная. 
Вот насчет родственности чура и чурбана - это я не уверен, уточню.  
~  
Нет, похоже это случайное созвучие.
Искон. Суф. производное от той же основы (чур- < *keur- «рубить, резать»), что чурбак, чурбан, черта (с перегласовкой ь/у), кора. Чурка, чурбак, чурбан буквально — «обрубок» (дерева).

http://www.onlineslovari.com/etimologicheskiy_slovar_russkogo_yazyika/page/churka.5945/
(Шанский)

Хотя он и "чур" возводит к той же основе... Ой... Сомневаюсь я все-таки в родственности.

Comment: Нет, не возражаю :)
Те не менее, общего слишком много, не только созвучие. Чуром вполне мог быть грубо рубленный чурбан, с чертами лица. Скорее всего, от того и пошло - чурбан безчувственный, с чего бы это человека чурбаном называть?

Comment: Сюда же "чересчур" - "то, чего не было у предков", сомнительное нововведение.

Answer (score 0):

Всем здравия!
Комментировать не могу, потому ответом скажу про "чур" и "щур".

***Новый толково-словообразовательный словарь русского языка. Автор Т. Ф. Ефремова.:*** щур 1. м. Небольшая певчая птица семейства вьюрковых. 2. м. 1) Предок, родоначальник (в славянской мифологии). 2) перен. Домовой.
**Толковый словарь русского языка под ред. Д. Н. Ушакова:** ЩУР щура, м. Небольшая певчая птица из сем. вьюрковых. Словно дверь заскрипит малиновый щур. Кокорев.; ЩУР щура, м. (этнол.). В славянской мифологии - предок, родоначальник, домовой (ср. пращур).

А чуры - идолы, образы богов (как сказано выше). В родноверии/ведизме боги есть отцы, прародители, то есть пращур, щур. От сюда и есть некая параллель между этими словами.

Всем добрых дел!

Answer (score 0):

> В. О. Ключевский писал: «Обоготворённый предок чествовался под именем
>   Чура, в церковнославянской форме Щура; эта форма доселе уцелела в
>   сложном слове пращур… Предание, оставившее следы в языке, придаёт Чуру
>   значение, одинаковое с римским Термом, значение сберегателя родовых
>   полей и границ». Такое же объяснение есть в Малом словаре Брокгауза и
>   Ефрона: «Чур, славянск. мифол. божество пограничн. знаков,
>   покровительствовало приобретению и наживе. Символ — чурки и чурбаны,
>   то есть межевые знаки».
>   (**[Источник](https://books.google.ru/books?id=8sPTCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT241&lpg=PT241&dq=%D0%92.%20%D0%9E.%20%D0%9A%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BB:%20%C2%AB%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%A7%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=P3jrlnte2F&sig=aStQ2EYVqB7Op1i-jdyrEDjZUJY&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwje3cGbopvRAhWLWSwKHXSABE0Q6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%D0%92.%20%D0%9E.%20%D0%9A%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BB%3A%20%C2%AB%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%A7%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0&f=false)**)
>
> Тем не менее, уже ко времени Макса Фасмера накопились значительные
>   сомнения в существовании такого божества. Сам он отвергает связь слова
>   «чурка» и семантики границы с выражением «чур меня!» Как недостоверные
>   этимолог приводит версии происхождения междометия от русского «чёрт»,
>   заимствования из греческого или чувашского.
>
> По мнению Д. К. Зеленина и А. Б. Страхова, слово восходит к греч.
>   κύρ(ιος) «господь, господин» и изначально значило «Господи!», «Боже,
>   упаси!».
>
> Н. И. Толстой впервые связал возникновение междометия «чур» с
>   фаллической символикой. Эта гипотеза впоследствии пополнилась новыми
>   данными и является актуальной до сих пор. ([**Источник**](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D1%83%D1%80?wprov=sfla1))